# For a matrix $A$, does $A^3=I_n$ mean that $\det(A)=1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Here, $A\in \mathbb{K}^{n,n}$ ($n$ by $n$ matrix) where $\frac{1}{2} \in \mathbb{K}$ where $\mathbb{K}$ is a field.

I think this is true. Since, using the fact that $\det(AB)=\det(A) \cdot \det(B)$ for $n$ by $n$ matrices, we can arrive at $[\det(A)]^3=1$ so $\det(A)=1$.

Am I right?

Comment: $x^3=1$ might have many solutions, depending on the field.

Comment: As Spenser's answer shows, it depends on the field $\mathbb{K}$.  If $1$ is the only cube root of $1$ in $\mathbb{K}$, then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, if your field is $\Bbb C$ and $3$ does not divide $n$, then $A=e^{2\pi i/3}I$ has $A^3=1$ but $\det(A)=e^{2n\pi i/3}\neq 1$.

Indeed,
$$\det(A)=\det(e^{2\pi i/3}I)=(e^{2\pi i/3})^n\det(I)=e^{2n\pi i/3},$$
and
$$A^3=(e^{2\pi i/3}I)^3=(e^{2\pi i/3})^3I=e^{2\pi i}I=I.$$

The point is that the equation $z^3=1$ could have many solutions if the field is different than $\Bbb R$. Over $\Bbb C$, for example, this equation has three solutions: $1$, $e^{2\pi i/3}$ and $e^{4\pi i/3}$.

Comment: Why not make it simpler and use $ \displaystyle A = \begin{bmatrix} e^{2\pi i/3} & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\  0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots \\  0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots \\  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \end{bmatrix} \text{ ?} \qquad$

Answer (score 0):

$${\bf A}^3 = {\bf I} \implies \lambda_k({\bf A}^3) = 1 \Leftrightarrow \lambda_k({\bf A})^3 = 1, \forall k$$
As others mention this is a restriction on $\lambda$ which all are in the scalar field of matrix elements.

However the determinant can be written as the product of eigenvalues
$$\det({\bf A}) = \prod_i \lambda_i({\bf A})$$

Now it depends on the scalar field what values this product of "third roots of unity" can take.